# How to check whether a username already exists?

Tags: 8, users, page-controller

I had created a controller where I can create a new user programmitically by the following code.

```
$user = User::create();

      //Mandatory settings
      $user->setPassword($password);
      $user->enforceIsNew();
      $user->setEmail($email);

      //This username must be unique and accept only a-Z,0-9, - _ @ .
      $user->setUsername($username);

      //Optional settings
      $language = 'en';
      $user->set("init", 'email');
      $user->set("langcode", $language);
      $user->set("preferred_langcode", $language);
      $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $language);
      $user->activate();

      //Save user
      $user->save();
      drupal_set_message("User with uid " . $user->id() . " saved!\n");

      $uid = $user->id();
```

I am passing all variables via postman by POST method. I am using email as the username. But I want to check a condition (whether the username is already exist ) before the user creation. How can I write the if condition?

Comment: It's easy to end up with a race condition leading to unexpected results - can you give more details on exactly what you're trying to do? It might make more sense to try and create a user and detect a constraint violation (duplicate usernames aren't allowed) than to explicitly make a call trying to check ahead-of-time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you can use a simple EntityQuery.

```
  $ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
        ->condition('name', 'USERNAME_TO_CHECK')
        ->range(0, 1)
        ->execute();
    if(!empty($ids)){
      //then this name already exists
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that works... ! How can i just print that id inside that $ids array...? When i try to print_r($ids) I got Array ( [28] => 28 ) ............. 28 is the uid... but how can i fetch that from $ids. I need to use this uid.

Comment: you can do $user_id = reset($ids) and then $existing_user = User::load($user_id);
don't forget to call use Drupal\user\Entity\User; in your file or php class.

Comment: Much shorter version: `$account = User::loadByProperties(['name' => 'foo']);`. Then just test `$account` for `NULL`.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of custom one-off checks, you should use the validation API.

Before saving, call $user->validate(). That tells you if anything with the values isn't OK, there is also a limit on what characters are allowed for the username/email and so on.

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/entity-validation-api-overview.